# Very confused about responsive CSS media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, retina-display

I don't expect a one size fits all answer here, but I've been reading blog after blog on "the best way to design a site to make it responsive" and I'm more confused now than when I started.

The overwhelming opinion seems to be "Don't use device specific MQ's, use breakpoints instead".

I totally get this and it makes perfect sense, but in the real world it simply doesn't work.

For example.

Design a site that looks great at max-width 800px on a desktop and all is well. View it on a small screen device and it also looks great. But view that site on an iPhone 6 and everything that was big and bold at 800px on the desktop is tiny due to the increased resolution of retina devices.

Surely the only way to address this is by using device specific MQ's - which everybody screams isn't a good idea.

I'm really confused now.

Am I missing part of the story here somewhere?

I can't stomach another blog right now as my head is spinning, so I thought I'd ask the pro's ;)

Any pointers for addressing this specific (retina device) issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the viewport meta between your `<head>` tags `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />` Your website is scaling to the devices width

Comment: you can also write pixel ratio MQ without being device-specific - see [retina display media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)

Comment: This is too big of a topic for a clear answer. Unfortunately I would have to suggest you continue learning... just trust that it DOES work if done correctly.

Comment: Oh Chuck I have no doubt that it works when done correctly, that's why I asked the question because everything I've read and followed so far has thrown up the issue I mentioned. So I knew I was missing a big piece of the puzzle somewhere ;)

Comment: "the increased resolution of retina devices" doesn't make elements small. a font-size of 16px is still 16px big on retina. not sure what you are talking about here. also read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: @vlrprbttst sorry but you are wrong. The physical pixel is not the same as the optical pixel. In practice, pixels are pixels, but visually is not the same. You can read something like this: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/master-css-pixels-retina-displays-8122955 . When you increase the pixel ratio, obviously, the size of one physical pixel doesn't change, but the optical pixel (the size we can see in the screen) is different. See my answer and the link I've attached.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude this gets solved using the appropriate viewport meta tag in <head> which is (usually) <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> and is mandatory if you are creating a responsive website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very broad topic, but in big words, you can avoid it changing your layout from hard-pixel to relative meassures (`em`, `rem`, `vh/vw`, etc).

If you define this in the HTML tag:

```
 html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
 }
```

Then you can use `em/rem` meassures and you can make this:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 80rem) /* MQ 800 pixels no matter pixel ratio */
```

If you define a font-size for example in pixels, with a pixel ratio of 3, the font-size will be a 1/3 of the specified. But if you make in `em` it will be the same in all devices.

### Example in hard-pixels:

```
div { 
   width: 300px;
}
```

- **Device pixel ratio: 1** > Result: 300px;
- **Device pixel ratio: 2** > Result: 150px;
- **Device pixel ratio: 3** > Result: 100px;

### Example in relative measures

```
div { 
    width: 30rem;
}
```

- **Device pixel ratio: 1** > Result: 300px;
- **Device pixel ratio: 2** > Result: 300px;
- **Device pixel ratio: 3** > Result: 300px;

Good luck

### EDIT

In comments, you can see more explanation about `62.5%` defined font-size and why it's a great feature.

Comment: isn't `html` `font-size` as a percentage a bit counter intuitive? What is it a percentage of?

Comment: Yowzah, so that's a good few weeks of trawling through my css lined up for me then! So converting everything from px to em (font-wise) will take care of this then? How about images and boxes? Should they all be sized in % instead of hard px too?

Comment: @Martin, that calculation is as old as CSS language. That percentage (62.5%) allows you to write `em` meassures like `pixels / 10`, and with it `300px == 30 em`

Comment: @Grant I recommend you to transform with `rem` (root em), otherwise you'll have problems where a div have a font-size defined. Images and boxes will be better with `rem`  too, not percents. The only percent neccesary is the `62.5%` (it's not really necessary but helps you to know what the hell are you writing).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes, but out of curiosity what is it 62.5% of, and from that how is the absolute size derived?

Comment: @Martin the absolute size is defined in the browser, by the user. The default it's often `16 px` , but users can edit in the browser's preferences. With the `62.5%` you don't override the user preference, so this method is the best responsive. If you make the `62.5% of 16px` you'll obtain `10px`, so the default font-size will be `10px` and the `em` will be calculated by this value.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude bloody hell no wonder I was confused so easily. Haha, actually I think I've probably read more comments on how confused professional CSS designers get with aspects of responsive design than I have solutions. I can see this is going to be a steep learning curve.

Comment: It's easy if you follow this rules: 1) Add the 62.5% percent to `html` tag. 2) Write sizes in `rem` (`px / 10`, so `100px == 10rem`). 3) Write media queries with the same meassure (`rem`). 4) Test in desktop, mobile and retina.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude that is going to be my bible! I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks man ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget the meta viewport tag. It helps you a lot

Comment: I'm sorry, but this reply is simply not correct with regards to how pixels and ems etc work. The `px` measurement _is also relative_ and has basically nothing to do with physical pixels. It is defined on the same scale as `em`, `rem` etc. There is no "hard pixels". If you set something as `width: 16px` and use the default browser font size (for example) which is 16px, then `width: 1em` and `width: 16px` will mean the exact same thing. The difference in rendering between devices with different DPR is down to what viewport is used.

Answer (score 1):

Add the viewport meta between your `<head>` tags

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Your website is scaling to the devices width

Comment: Ahh that's something that I haven't seen addressed on anything I've read so far. Many thanks for this.

Comment: Your media queries are probably functioning as you intended, but without the meta tag your site won't be effected by them as it's not respecting the devices width.

Comment: To be fair I haven't even started on the main site yet. I just threw a quick test site together to get my head around the responsive thing and it threw up this problem right out of the box. Will add this and see how I get on though. Thanks again ;)

Comment: In general, I suspect this is the missing piece the OP is after. The `maximum-scale=1.0` bit is redundant, however, as it prevents zooming on mobile devices, creating an accessibility and usability problem. A lot of devs throw it in there out of habit, mostly because there are/were bugs on older devices with e.g. fixed positioning unless zoom is locked. The better solution in my opinion is to leave zoom as-is, and avoid perf-heavy things like fixed position on older devices instead.